# Shopping Cart Price Rule not applying when specifying the category in "actions"

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart-price-rules

Magento Shopping Cart Price Rule not applying when i add the Rule for the specific category. It is working fine for SKU but not for the category. 
Any admin section settings that are preventing it from this?

[image]

Comment: Could you please share the screenshot of the error you are facing?

Comment: the error is when i specify the category in the shopping cart rule it is not applying

Comment: no other errors at all

Comment: Can you please share the screenshot of the rule you set

Comment: yes, i have updated the question. please check

Answer (score 0):

There are several possible reasons for this. First and most likely is the the product is in multiple categories, hence it might work more effectively if you chance the rule to "Category **contains** 85". This will then apply to products which are in category 85 but also in others.

You should also check for any active Catalogue Price Rules which could be affecting the product, as all price rules can be set to be exclusive, which restricts a product to only use one promotion at a time. This can cause unexpected conflicts sometimes, particularly in a situation like this.